# Pass relative files into function using javascript file constructor

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to load in a relative file address into a function previously used by a file reader. On the site, I had a button that would let you pick local files to be loaded into a graphics renderer. I want to use a url to access these files relatively instead, but I can't figure out how to bind them to a file object. I have been using [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) mozilla documentation to try and figure it out.

Here is the code that was used originally:

```
// function that takes file input and renders the image
function readFiles(){
  // Deal with file input
  if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    var file1 = document.getElementById('fileinput').files[0];
    var file2 = document.getElementById('fileinput').files[1];

    // Call the file analyzer
    fileAnalyzer( file1, file2 );

  } else {
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported by your browser.');
  }
}
```

Here is the code that I want to update:

```
// load cube button
  var loadcube = document.getElementById('loadcube');
  loadcube.onclick = function(evt) {
    var file1 = new File([], "Object files/cube3.coor" );
    var file2 = new File([], "Object files/cube3.poly" );
    fileAnalyzer( file1, file2);
  }
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to load files that exist on the website into memory?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to asynchronously fetch the resources, convert them to a `Blob`, and then construct a `File` like this:

```
function fetchAsFile(path) {
  return fetch(path).then(function (response) {
    return response.blob()
  }).then(function (blob) {
    return new File([blob], path)
  })
}

var loadcube = document.getElementById('loadcube')

loadcube.addEventlistener('click', function () {
  var p1 = fetchAsFile('Object files/cube3.coor')
  var p2 = fetchAsFile('Object files/cube3.poly')

  Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(function (files) {
    fileAnalyzer(files[0], files[1])
  })
})
```

Using ES2017 `async` / `await`, you can simplify the above like this:

```
async function fetchAsFile(path) {
  let response = await fetch(path)
  let blob = await response.blob()

  return new File([blob], path)
}

var loadcube = document.getElementById('loadcube')

loadcube.addEventlistener('click', async function () {
  let p1 = fetchAsFile('Object files/cube3.coor')
  let p2 = fetchAsFile('Object files/cube3.poly')

  let files = await Promise.all([p1, p2])

  fileAnalyzer(files[0], files[1])
})
```